# Qualtrics Survey custom CSS

Tags: css, qualtrics

> How do I change the color of my answer choices button in my Qualtrics
>   Survey?

I have a scale agree to strongly disagree and a different color depending on their answer choice. green for clicking agree, red for clicking disagree, orange for clicking neutral etc. I know I need custom CSS. **is it even possible?**

[Here](https://eu.qualtrics.com/jfe/preview/SV_0GOdBufbOxpIxVP?Q_CHL=preview) is a link for my sample survey

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please see how colors are being added to the other elements of the site and follow that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with just CSS because the labels don't have any classes or attributes to differentiate them.  You could do it with a combination of CSS and JavaScript.

One way would be to create CSS rules by classnames, then have JavaScript add the appropriate classname to each label.